# SSRS web url not displaying correctly after downgrade to 2016

Tags: reporting-services

I had to downgrade to SSRS 2016. When opening the web url I can only see the data folders in text and not getting the normal SSRS screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lChiT.png)

Tried to look in the config file but could not see anything out of order

Answer (score 1):

That looks like report server address, not the web portal address.

If you URL looks like this

```
http://myservername/reportserver
```

Then you should be using this

```
http://myservername/reports
```

This is the default address of the web portal. If this does not work Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager and look at the Web Portal URL

[image]